# Can someone explain this error for me 'HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Spring MVC'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring.

I have created maven project (that is, a spring-mvc project) for internship purposes.

My maven project structure :

[image]

Code for Controller :

```
package com.thp.project.vintud.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class UserController  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String index(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Liste of users");
    return "user";
 }
}
```

user.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>User List</title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting a 404 not found status. Why ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason for 404 status** : Your Dispatcherservlet is not able to find the resource, that is, `user.jsp`.

Remember to remove this below from web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
   ......
</welcome-file-list>
```

As this interferes with the dispatcherservlet for view parsing.

Follow this example for simple spring-mvc project.

-> Create a simple web-project. Note : For maven, the structure is different. The project structure for the simple web-project.

```
spring-mvc-demo
│
│
├───src
│   └───com
│       └───thp
│           └───project
│               └───vintud
|                   └───controller
│                          DemoController.java
│
└───WebContent
    ├───META-INF
    │       MANIFEST.MF
    │
    └───WEB-INF
        │   applicationContext.xml
        │   web.xml
        │
        ├───lib
        │       javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
        │       javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
        │       spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-aspects-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-aspects-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-aspects-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-context-indexer-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-context-indexer-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-context-indexer-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-context-support-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-context-support-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-context-support-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-expression-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-expression-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-expression-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-instrument-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-instrument-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-instrument-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-jcl-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-jcl-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-jcl-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-jdbc-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-jdbc-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-jdbc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-jms-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-jms-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-jms-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-orm-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-orm-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-orm-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-oxm-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-oxm-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-oxm-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-test-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-test-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-test-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-webflux-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-webflux-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-webflux-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │       spring-websocket-5.0.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
        │       spring-websocket-5.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
        │       spring-websocket-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
        │
        └───view
                user.jsp
```

-> Create a controller.

```
package com.thp.project.vintud.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class DemoController  {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String getUserList(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("message", "List of users");
     return "user";
   }
}
```

user.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>This is Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.thp.project.vintud" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Output :

[image]